# Python parallel apply on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I have this part of code in my application.
What I want is to iterate over each row in my data frame (pandas) and modify column to function result.

I tried to implement it with multiprocessing, but I'm to see if there is any faster and easier to implement way to do it.
Is there any simple way to run this part in parallel?

```
def _format(data: pd.DataFrame, context: pd.DataFrame)
    data['context'] = data.apply(lambda row: get_context_value(context, row), axis=1)
```

The data frame I work with is not to large (10,000 - 100,000) and the function to evaluate the value to assign to the column take around 250ms - 500ms for one row. But the whole process for the size of the data frame takes to much.

Thanks

Comment: Didn't test, but this looks promising: https://gist.github.com/govorunov/3d1a214dc067b7f9df54d481f46ffb68, works with joblib.

Comment: Unless your dataframe is ridiculously small, do not use multiprocessing, because doing so will involve copying data between processes. And instead of trying to use it just wonder whether Pandas vectorized methods can be used. Chances are that performance will be much better that latter way...

Comment: Thanks, I don't have large data frame (I tested for 10,000), this code takes more than 30min (Until I stopped it) and with multi process 10 min and finished, which is still to much. (The get_context_value takes around 50ms)
Maybe I should use pandas DF

Answer (score 0):

I have a project which it is done there: https://github.com/mjafari98/dm-classification/blob/main/inference.py

```py
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np


def parallelize(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_of_processes)
    pool = Pool(num_of_processes)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

def run_on_subset(func, data_subset):
    return data_subset.apply(func, axis=1)

def parallelize_on_rows(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    return parallelize(data, partial(run_on_subset, func), num_of_processes)


def a_function(row):
    ...do something ...
    return row

df = ...somedf...
new_df = parallelize_on_rows(df, a_function)
```

Comment: Thanks, This is similar to what I tried, but I noticed It didn't gave me the output I expected.
I don't have very large data frame(10,000-100,000) and the get_context_value function takes around 50 MS but the whole data frame still took a lot of time. How can I know the num_processes limit or maybe I just need better hardware?